# Manga about a guy trapped in a simulation/game

Tags: story-identification, manga

I read this manga maybe 2/3 years ago. He is given targets (usually women), which he at first thinks he can do anything with them (i.e. sexual assault). However, the system tasks him with actually figuring out a dark secret with each of his targets. He has the ability to 'scan' people, revealing some information about them. However, he cannot fully scan higher profile targets. He can buy extra items to assist him and will also be resurrected if he dies.

Answer (score 1):

This sound like  [Ore no Genjitsu wa Renai Game?](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=144731).

Except for the sexual assault part.

> One day, 25-year-old Hasegawa Ryou wakes up to see a holographic screen floating in front of him. The screen prompts him to save/load files and an item shop, as well as his stats. It seems like he’s been sucked into some erotic love game, since his stats depend on seducing women and “capturing” them.
> After finding a target and going through game-like options, Ryou thinks he knows what he has to do to “capture” his target. Surely he needs to have sex with her, right? And yet when the woman turns out to be a murderer, Ryou finds out the shocking truth: he has to capture these women and unveil their secrets! And if he fails, he dies.

I believe there are some other chinese light novel about system IRL which similar with this but their content is the same story development like what you tell. So I will need more info if this one isn't right.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, he does try to assault his first target, thinking it's that sort of a game, in part because the in-game items provided are things like skeleton keys and knockout-sprays.