# Manga where the protagonist needs to solve girls' quests

Tags: story-identification, manga

The protagonist is teleported to an alternative world where he needs to make the girls fall in love with him, then he gains some skills like an invisible sword. When he finishes these "quests", he will be able to bring one of them to the real world. He has the ability to save and load like checkpoints of games.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, was the "alternate world" another version of our world or some kind of medieval sword 'n' sorcery world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good chance this is [*Ore no Genjitsu wa Ren’ai Game?? ka to Omottara Inochigake no Game datta*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ore-no-genjitsu-wa-renai-game-ka-to-omottara-inochigake-no-game-datta) (one translated English title being *The world I thought was a dating sim turned out to be a death game*).

[image: Front cover of Ore no Genjitsu wa Ren’ai Game?? ka to Omottara Inochigake no Game datta]

> One day, 25-year-old Hasegawa Ryou wakes up to see a holographic screen floating in front of him. The screen prompts him to save/load files and an item shop, as well as his stats. It seems like he’s been sucked into some erotic love game, since his stats depend on seducing women and “capturing” them. After finding a target and going through game-like options, Ryou thinks he knows what he has to do to “capture” his target. Surely he needs to have sex with her, right? And yet when the woman turns out to be a murderer, Ryou finds out the shocking truth: he has to capture these women and unveil their secrets! And if he fails, he dies...

There's the ability to load and save, and the sex aspect. Secondly, as per [the Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/i68fi9/cant_remember_name/) I found with a search for `isekai "invisible sword"`, there is an invisible sword ability. However, as far as I can tell (I'll admit that I've only read a few chapters), he is not transported to another world, but rather just wakes up with this ability.

Comment: Ah, previously showed up at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/235384/manga-about-a-guy-trapped-in-a-simulation-game