# Main character is killed and he awakens a system to kill

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, isekai, reincarnation

I am trying to remember a story the main character is a guy who thought he had a chance with a girl, until he was killed and sent a couple hours into the past where he awakens a system.

The images were maybe black and white, but maybe colored. I remember he would kill them or turn them in, in order to survive. I read this about a year ago.

Comment: By "a system", do you mean something like a video game interface that he can use? Who is he killing or turning? Are they other players? Targets designated by the system? Random people? Was this a teenager? Adult? Adolescent? Does he only get sent back in time once, or does it happen every time he dies?

Comment: well he was a teenager no not a game he was turning them in and sometimes killing them if he had a choice and the system ha to do it like a mision game like a dateing sim

Comment: Hmm... does it involve him being able to buy items, like a key that opens any kick, but only works ten times, and his first target, he thinks he's supposed to have sex with her, but she's actually killing the men she sleeps with?

Comment: And what happens when he "turns them"? Do they turn into something? Does he turn them into the authorities? Are they forced to flee him, like undead facing a cleric?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by 'a system'?

Comment: @ancientswordrage: it's a shorthand for "a system for leveling" in LitRPG manga and Isekai circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partial match would be *[Ore no Genjitsu wa Ren’ai Game?? ka to Omottara Inochigake no Game datta](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ore-no-genjitsu-wa-renai-game-ka-to-omottara-inochigake-no-game-datta)*, as per [Manga where the protagonist need to solve girl's quests](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/238304/manga-where-the-protagonist-need-to-solve-girls-quests).

[image: Front cover of Ore no Genjitsu wa Ren’ai Game?? ka to Omottara Inochigake no Game datta]

> One day, 25-year-old Hasegawa Ryou wakes up to see a holographic screen floating in front of him. The screen prompts him to save/load files and an item shop, as well as his stats. It seems like he’s been sucked into some erotic love game, since his stats depend on seducing women and “capturing” them. After finding a target and going through game-like options, Ryou thinks he knows what he has to do to “capture” his target. Surely he needs to have sex with her, right? And yet when the woman turns out to be a murderer, Ryou finds out the shocking truth: he has to capture these women and unveil their secrets! And if he fails, he dies...

It has someone with a system who has to reveal the secrets of his targets (or maybe kill them), but he is not killed prior to gaining the system, and he's older than a teenager. That said, when he does die, he resets to his last "save point" (albeit without items used), which was some hours before for his first death. Also, arguably, he looks like a teenager.

[image: First page of the manga]

Comment: If this is not the correct answer, please consider using the reasons why it does not match to clarify your question. :) Sometimes that's the benefit of partial or wrong answers, that they can lead to you realizing new things about the question that you had not included.

Comment: Yes it is thank you very much 