# need help finding manga // sort of a game isekai, "ingame" items, girl with bodyguards

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, magical-items

I remember reading a manga about this boy who I think was in some sort of game where he had to help certain people with requests in order to reach the next level. I cant for the life of me remember the title cause it was in Japanese, but he was able to buy and use certain items that helped him throughout the series. There was also this girl with bodyguards who was fascinated with him and sort of followed him around trying to see who he was. There was this one part where he reversed events that saved her from a helicopter crash (i think? its been a long time lol).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: I dont remember exactly, but like 3-4 years ago on some random manga site

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Can you describe the girl mentioned? Info about her appearance, personality would help. And if you remember other details like if the protagonist had a system, skills. And what was the mood like?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

This may be [*Ore no Genjitsu wa Ren’ai Game?? ka to Omottara Inochigake no Game datta*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ore-no-genjitsu-wa-renai-game-ka-to-omottara-inochigake-no-game-datta) (one translated English title being *The world I thought was a dating sim turned out to be a death game*).

[image: Front cover of Ore no Genjitsu wa Ren’ai Game?? ka to Omottara Inochigake no Game datta]

> One day, 25-year-old Hasegawa Ryou wakes up to see a holographic screen floating in front of him. The screen prompts him to save/load files and an item shop, as well as his stats. It seems like he’s been sucked into some erotic love game, since his stats depend on seducing women and “capturing” them. After finding a target and going through game-like options, Ryou thinks he knows what he has to do to “capture” his target. Surely he needs to have sex with her, right? And yet when the woman turns out to be a murderer, Ryou finds out the shocking truth: he has to capture these women and unveil their secrets! And if he fails, he dies...

[This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/zowijc/cant_find_this_manga_and_i_dont_know_the_name/) mentions the girl with the bodyguards:

> It's a manga where the protagonist is a guy, and he gets like powers to stop/ or manipulate time (I don't remember) and the first thing he does is use it on his fenale neighbor, but when the time manipulation wears off she gets a knife and tries to stab him? He goes back in time or whatever and then doesn't do that. I remember later in the story he meets this girl who has a lot of bodyguards and threatens to kill him or whatever, and she is like the daughter of some yakuza boss?

It is not an isekai story, though, but one where he wakes up with the ability.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/238304/23243